# Proof that {(x,y) | x ∈ y} is not a set

Tags: set-theory

*How to solve this problem without using the foundation axiom:*

There is no set consisting exactly of pairs (x, y) where x ∈ y, i.e. {(x, y) | x ∈ y}
is not a set.

Is this somehow related to Russell's paradox?

Comment: What axioms *are* we allowed to use?

Comment: I actually don't know what is allowed in this problem. This is my assignment.

Comment: What set theory have you been learning in the course? If it's $\mathsf{ZF}$, you're probably allowed $\mathsf{ZF-}$. (In case anyone doesn't know, $\mathsf{ZF-}$ means the $\mathsf{ZF}$ axioms other than foundation.)

Comment: I would recommend going to whomever assigned you the question and asking for clarification on what is allowed.

Comment: I'm assuming all in ZF (and C wouldn't be useful regardless) except that every non-empty set A contains an element that is disjoint from A.

Comment: Why isn’t $\{ (1, \{1\}) \}$ an example of such a set?

Comment: I don't seem to understand the question, I would assume that $ {(1, \Bbb R), (a, {a, b, c})}} $ and would be a counterexample.

Comment: Adam, Neptune: Both of your sets are missing quite a number of ordered pairs to qualify as $\{(x,y)\mid x\in y\}$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson You gave a set with **a** pair $(x,y)$ satisfying $x \in y$. We are talking about the collection (is not a set) of **ALL** such pairs.

Comment: @Neptune You gave a set with **two** pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying $x \in y$. We are talking about the collection (is not a set) of **ALL** such pairs.

Comment: You didn’t say “of all pairs” in the question though.

Answer (score 1):

If $S = \{(x,y)\mid x\in y\}$ is a set, its cardinality won't be bounded above. More rigorously, we can construct an injective map from the power set (really any set) $2^S\rightarrow S$ by sending $X$ to the pair $(X, \{X\})$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $b$ is not the empty set.
Select $a \in b$. Then, unless I am misunderstanding this problem, $(a, b) \in \{ (x, y) \colon x \in y \} $. If $\{ (x, y) \colon x \in y \} $ is a set, then so is $\{ y \colon \exists x (x \in y) \} $. If the collection of all nonempty sets is a set then so is $\{ y \colon \exists x (x \in y) \} \cup \{ \varnothing \} $, the collection of all sets. The collection of all sets is not a set.